# Авторизация VK php

Tags: php, вконтакте

Использую код:

```
$client_id = ''; // ID приложения
$client_secret = ''; // Защищённый ключ
$redirect_uri = ''; // Адрес сайта

$url = 'http://oauth.vk.com/authorize';

$params = array(
    'client_id'     => $client_id,
    'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
    'response_type' => 'code'
);

echo $link = '<p><a href="' . $url . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params)) . '">Аутентификация через ВКонтакте</a></p>';if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$result = false;
$params = array(
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
    'code' => $_GET['code'],
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri
);

$token = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);

if (isset($token['access_token'])) {
    $params = array(
        'uids'         => $token['user_id'],
        'fields'       => 'uid,first_name,last_name,screen_name,sex,bdate,photo_big',
        'access_token' => $token['access_token']
    );

    $userInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);
    if (isset($userInfo['response'][0]['uid'])) {
        $userInfo = $userInfo['response'][0];
        $result = true;
    }
}

if ($result) {
    echo "Социальный ID пользователя: " . $userInfo['uid'] . '<br />';
    echo "Имя пользователя: " . $userInfo['first_name'] . '<br />';
    echo "Ссылка на профиль пользователя: " . $userInfo['screen_name'] . '<br />';
    echo "Пол пользователя: " . $userInfo['sex'] . '<br />';
    echo "День Рождения: " . $userInfo['bdate'] . '<br />';
    echo '<img src="' . $userInfo['photo_big'] . '" />'; echo "<br />";
}
```

}

После выполнения получаю ошибку: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но если перехожу по ссылке в ошибке, получаю нормальный json ответ с нужными данными: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем может быть проблема? С cURL нету опыта работы, говорю сразу. Может кто-то подскажет рабочую авторизацию, или в чем ошибка? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы заходите по ссылке, вы авторизованный пользователь, но сервер таковым не является. Можете убедиться в этом пройдя по ссылке, например, в режиме инкогнито. Чтобы получать доступ к информации вам нужно авторизовать сервер, как это сделать написано в документации VK api.

Comment: Я использую эту авторизацию в `<head>`:
`<script src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.init({
    apiId: xx
  });
</script>
`

Answer (score 1):

Там проблема в том что много разных авторизаций ВК. есть авторизация сайта, есть авторизация приложения, а есть стандалон авторизация. Почитай еще раз ВК апи. я с ним разобрался за день. Там все просто и весь код у меня заработал сразу же.
Если что пиши конкретнее для чего авторизация используется, т.к. есть нюансы.

Comment: Вообще я хочу реализовать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку вылетало pop-up окно для авторизации на сайте, после чего уже средствами php можно было вытащить инфу о пользователе

Comment: Тебе нужно тогда искать авторизация  на сайте через vk api. Там все просто и подключается там не openapi.js а другой файл